# Can Vista x64 or Windows 7 x64 drivers be used for Windows Server 2008 x64, including R2?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, drivers, 64-bit, windows-server-2008

*Background:* I'm planning to install **Windows Server 2008 x64** on a **desktop class system** that I'm building using a recent Intel mainboard.  While it's *not* server-class hardware intended for production use, I develop web applications for a living and it's handy to have a non-virtual server O/S to develop/test against.  (There are non-trivial differences from workstation-class OS's to server-class OS's. Recall, say, Windows XP's IIS 5.1 vs. Windows Server 2003's IIS 6.0 with app pools, etc.)

I'm confident Windows Server 2008 x64 will *basically* work on the box, but I'd also want it to be able to do other useful things like: MP3 jukebox, video player.  (Consolidating functions will help keep the number of boxes in my lab to a minimum!)  Therefore, I'm wondering if I can get sound and video working on the box.  The Intel desktop board has current 64-bit drivers available for *both* Vista and Windows 7.

And so, the question: **Can Vista x64 or Windows 7 x64 drivers be used for Windows 2008 x64, including the forthcoming R2 edition?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to without any problem. The underlying kernel is the same for both Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2. I, personally, have not had any issues when using a "Windows Vista" driver on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: I agree (15 characters for Jeff)

Comment: Thanks.  What about the "signed" driver issue ... since both systems are x64 they would both already require signed drivers, right?

Comment: Yes, they have to be signed. If they aren't you would have to disable driver signing on every boot (or enter the driver test mode).

Comment: The two systems are so similar, they even have the same service pack: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a4dd31d5-f907-4406-9012-a5c3199ea2b3&displaylang=en